# How to configure fonts in multiple layout in next js app router?

Tags: next.js

Basically, I have two layout. BuyerLayout and SellerLayout and I want each to have their own font.

(I have already defined my font variables, I am using Tailwind.)

This is my structure.

In SellerLayout:

[image]

I made a variable of the `font-inter` and passed them to component.

I use it like this:

[image]

The same is true with the BuyerLayout.js

[image]

This is working as intended, but I want my code to be cleaner and efficient more as I think even though its only 3 components how i use the prop `fontFamily` inside them makes it so messy.

I can wrap them in `div` instead of fragment but wont that make the structure ugly as it will then be not very logical/intuitive?

```
    <div className={fontFamily}>
      <Header />
      <Dashboard>{children}</Dashboard>
      <Footer />
    </div>
```

If i can determine which font to use on RootLayout html or body tag then that would be a big help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :**

> *I can wrap them in div instead of fragment but wont that make the structure ugly as it will then be not very logical/intuitive?*

**Explaination :**

> Instead of passing 3 same props to 3 different components, just apply it to the div. As you have same font on them there's no point of repeating separately.

Infact, you can just :

**BuyerLayout.js**

```
<div className={'font-dmSans'}>
    <Header />
        <Dashboard>
            {children}
        </Dashboard>
    <Footer />
</div>
```

*Similarly for SellerLayout, pass font-Inter*

Answer (score 0):

You can create different wrappers for different fonts like this.

```
export const FontAWrapper = ({children}) => {
   return (
       <div className={{fontStyle1}}>
         {children}
       </div>
   )
}
```

```
export const FontBWrapper = ({children}) => {
   return (
       <div className={{fontStyle2}}>
         {children}
       </div>
   )
}
```

And use them in the App like this.

```
<FontAWrapper>
   {/* Other Stuffs */}
</FontAWrapper>

<FontBWrapper>
   {/* Other Stuffs */}
</FontBWrapper>
```

this will be helpful when you have a fixed number of fonts to be used over and over. So, when you change the component once, it will be reflected in all the places where you used the wrapper.